# How do you set up path for python3 on mac book pro?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I just got a new MacBook pro and startled the download process of python. I was able to download pythhon3 including pip3, the issue is when you download python mac is supposed to create a pathway in your nano bash profile. In this case, it didn't. Can anyone help me manually create the pathway? I have provided screenshots for assistance.[nano bash profile empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tylBG.png)

[python3 terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXrB1.png)

Comment: `export PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:${PATH}"` hopefully that works...!

Comment: try this `open ~/.bash_profile` it will open profile, if it's empty, add `export PATH="$PATH:/user/bin/python3"` and save . At terminal `echo $PATH` and you should see the added path.